# Meu array não está retornando, se não selecionar um valor anterior

Tags: ajax, array, return

Galera, estou fazendo um "monte seu pc" e tem algumas coisas que são opcionais e caso não seleciona um anterior, ele não me trás o valor do restando.

Exemplo:

- Gabinete
- Placa mae
- placa de video
- SDD(opcional)
- SO(opcional)
- fonte

Se eu não seleciono os opcionais ali, ele não me tras o valor nem a quantidade da fonte.

```
<form name="monteseupc">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="nome">Gabinetes</label>
                     <select class="form-control" style="width:40%"; nome="gabinete" id="SelectGabinete">
                      <option value="0">Escolha o Gabinete</option>
                      <?php while($rows_produtos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadoprodutos)) { ?>

                       <option value="<?php echo $rows_produtos['valor'] ?>" data-nome="<?php echo $rows_produtos['nome'] ?>"> <?php echo $rows_produtos['nome']." R$ ".number_format($rows_produtos['valor'],2,",",".") ?></option>
                       <?php } ?>
                     </select>
                     <input type="hidden" id="valorGabinete">
                     <input type="number" id="QGabinetes" pattern="[0-9]+([\,|\.][0-9]+)?" value="0" min="0" max="99" style="width:7%;" class="form-control">
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="processador">Processador</label>
                     <select nome="processador" id="selectProcessador">
                     <option value="0">Escolha o Processador</option> 
                       <?php while($rows_produtos2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadoprodutos2)) { ?>

                       <option value="<?php echo $rows_produtos2['valor'] ?>" data-nome="<?php echo $rows_produtos2['nome'] ?>"> <?php echo $rows_produtos2['nome']." R$ ".number_format($rows_produtos2['valor'],2,",",".") ?></option>
                       <?php } ?>

                     </select>
                     <input type="hidden" id="valorProcessador">
                     <input type="number" id="QProcessador" pattern="[0-9]+([\,|\.][0-9]+)?" value="0" max="99" min="0" style="width:7%" class="form-control">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="placamae">Placa Mãe</label>
                     <select nome="placamae" id="selectPlacamae">
                     <option value="0">Escolha a Placa Mãe</option> 
                      <?php while($rows_produtos3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadoprodutos3)) { ?>

                       <option value="<?php echo $rows_produtos3['valor']?>" data-nome="<?php echo $rows_produtos3['nome'] ?>"> <?php echo $rows_produtos3['nome']." R$ ".number_format($rows_produtos3['valor'],2,",",".") ?></option>
                       <?php } ?>

                     </select>


let arrayG = new Array(),
    arrayP = new Array(),
    arrayPm = new Array(),
    arrayMe = new Array(),
    arrayPv = new Array(),
    arrayHD = new Array(),
    arraySSD = new Array(),
    arraySO = new Array(),
    arrayGr = new Array(),
    arrayWc = new Array(),
    arrayC = new Array(),
    arrayF = new Array(),
    arrayMo = new Array(),
    arrayTe = new Array(),
    arrayHe = new Array(),
    arrayMon = new Array(),
    arrayAda = new Array(),
    arrayG1 = new Array(),
    arrayP1 = new Array(),
    arrayPm1 = new Array(),
    arrayMe1 = new Array(),
    arrayPv1 = new Array(),
    arrayHD1 = new Array(),
    arraySSD1 = new Array(),
    arraySO1 = new Array(),
    arrayGr1 = new Array(),
    arrayWc1 = new Array(),
    arrayC1 = new Array(),
    arrayF1 = new Array(),
    arrayMo1 = new Array(),
    arrayTe1 = new Array(),
    arrayHe1 = new Array(),
    arrayMon1 = new Array(),
    arrayAda1 = new Array();
$("#SelectGabinete").change(function() {
    $("#valorGabinete").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoGabinetes").html("Gabinete Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayG1 = [$("#valorGabinete").val()]
});
$("#selectProcessador").change(function() {
    $("#valorProcessador").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoProcessador").html("Processador Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayP1 = [$("#valorProcessador").val()]
});
$("#selectPlacamae").change(function() {
    $("#valorPlacamae").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoPlacamae").html("Placa mãe Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayPm1 = [$("#valorPlacamae").val()]
});
$("#selectMemoria").change(function() {
    $("#valorMemoria").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoMemoria").html("Memória Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayMe1 = [$("#valorMemoria").val()]
});
$("#selectPlacadevideo").change(function() {
    $("#valorPlacadevideo").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoPlacadevideo").html("Placa de video Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayPv1 = [$("#valorPlacadevideo").val()]
});
$("#selectHD").change(function() {
    $("#valorHD").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoHD").html("HD Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayHD1 = [$("#valorHD").val()]
});
$("#selectSSD").change(function() {
    $("#valorSSD").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoSSD").html("SSD Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arraySSD1 = [$("#valorSSD").val()]
});
$("#selectSO").change(function() {
    $("#valorSO").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoSO").html("SO Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arraySO1 = [$("#valorSO").val()]
});
$("#selectGravador").change(function() {
    $("#valorGravador").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoGravador").html("Gravador Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayGr1 = [$("#valorGravador").val()]
});
$("#selectWcooler").change(function() {
    $("#valorWcooler").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoWcooler").html("Water Cooler Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayWc1 = [$("#valorWcooler").val()]
});
$("#selectCooler").change(function() {
    $("#valorCooler").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoCooler").html("Cooler Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayC1 = [$("#valorCooler").val()]
});
$("#selectFonte").change(function() {
    $("#valorFonte").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoFonte").html("Fonte Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayF1 = [$("#valorFonte").val()]
});
$("#selectMouse").change(function() {
    $("#valorMouse").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoMouse").html("Mouse Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayMo1 = [$("#valorMouse").val()]
});
$("#selectTeclado").change(function() {
    $("#valorTeclado").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoTeclado").html("Teclado Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayTe1 = [$("#valorTeclado").val()]
});
$("#selectHeadset").change(function() {
    $("#valorHeadset").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoHeadset").html("HeadSet Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayHe1 = [$("#valorHeadset").val()]
});
$("#selectMonitor").change(function() {
    $("#valorMonitor").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoMonitor").html("Monitor Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayMon1 = [$("#valorMonitor").val()]
});
$("#selectAdaptador").change(function() {
    $("#valorAdaptador").val($(this).val());
    $("#nomedoAdaptador").html("Adaptador Escolhido:<br><b>" + $(this).find(':selected').data('nome') + "</b><br><br>");
    arrayAda1 = [$("#valorAdaptador").val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QGabinetes]").change(function() {
    arrayG = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QProcessador]").change(function() {
    arrayP = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QPlacamae]").change(function() {
    arrayPm = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QMemoria]").change(function() {
    arrayMe = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QPlacadevideo]").change(function() {
    arrayPv = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QHD]").change(function() {
    arrayHD = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QSSD]").change(function() {
    arraySSD = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QSO]").change(function() {
    arraySO = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QGravador]").change(function() {
    arrayGr = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QWcooler]").change(function() {
    arrayWc = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QCooler]").change(function() {
    arrayC = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QFonte]").change(function() {
    arrayF = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QMouse]").change(function() {
    arrayMo = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QTeclado]").change(function() {
    arrayTe = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QHeadset]").change(function() {
    arrayHe = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QMonitor]").change(function() {
    arrayMon = [$(this).val()]
});
$("input[type=number][id=QAdaptador]").change(function() {
    arrayAda = [$(this).val()]
});
$("select").change(function() {
    let soma = (+$("#valorGabinete").val() * $("#QGabinetes").val()) + (+$("#valorProcessador").val() * $("#QProcessador").val()) + (+$("#valorPlacamae").val() * $("#QPlacamae").val()) + (+$("#valorMemoria").val() * $("#QMemoria").val()) + (+$("#valorPlacadevideo").val() * $("#QPlacadevideo").val()) + (+$("#valorHD").val() * $("#QHD").val()) + (+$("#valorSSD").val() * $("#QSSD").val()) + (+$("#valorSO").val() * $("#QSO").val()) + (+$("#valorGravador").val() * $("#QGravador").val()) + (+$("#valorWcooler").val() * $("#QWcooler").val()) + (+$("#valorCooler").val() * $("#QCooler").val()) + (+$("#valorFonte").val() * $("#QFonte").val()) + (+$("#valorMouse").val() * $("#QMouse").val()) + (+$("#valorTeclado").val() * $("#QTeclado").val()) + (+$("#valorHeadset").val() * $("#QHeadset").val()) + (+$("#valorMonitor").val() * $("#QMonitor").val()) + (+$("#valorAdaptador").val() * $("#QAdaptador").val());
    $("#totalProdutos").html("Total da compra R$ " + mascaraValor(soma.toFixed(2)));
    $("#valortotalprodutos").val(soma)
});
$("input[type=number]").change(function() {
    let soma = (+$("#valorGabinete").val() * $("#QGabinetes").val()) + (+$("#valorProcessador").val() * $("#QProcessador").val()) + (+$("#valorPlacamae").val() * $("#QPlacamae").val()) + (+$("#valorMemoria").val() * $("#QMemoria").val()) + (+$("#valorPlacadevideo").val() * $("#QPlacadevideo").val()) + (+$("#valorHD").val() * $("#QHD").val()) + (+$("#valorSSD").val() * $("#QSSD").val()) + (+$("#valorSO").val() * $("#QSO").val()) + (+$("#valorGravador").val() * $("#QGravador").val()) + (+$("#valorWcooler").val() * $("#QWcooler").val()) + (+$("#valorCooler").val() * $("#QCooler").val()) + (+$("#valorFonte").val() * $("#QFonte").val()) + (+$("#valorMouse").val() * $("#QMouse").val()) + (+$("#valorTeclado").val() * $("#QTeclado").val()) + (+$("#valorHeadset").val() * $("#QHeadset").val()) + (+$("#valorMonitor").val() * $("#QMonitor").val()) + (+$("#valorAdaptador").val() * $("#QAdaptador").val());
    $("#totalProdutos").html("Total da compra R$ " + mascaraValor(soma.toFixed(2)));
    $("#valortotalprodutos").val(soma)









    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
       let arrayQtd = arrayG.concat(arrayP.concat(arrayPm.concat(arrayMe.concat(arrayPv.concat(arrayHD.concat(arraySSD.concat(arraySO.concat(arrayGr.concat(arrayWc.concat(arrayC.concat(arrayF.concat(arrayMo.concat(arrayTe.concat(arrayHe.concat(arrayMon.concat(arrayAda)))))))))))))))),

          arrayValor = arrayG1.concat(arrayP1.concat(arrayPm1.concat(arrayMe1.concat(arrayPv1.concat(arrayHD1.concat(arraySSD1.concat(arraySO1.concat(arrayGr1.concat(arrayWc1.concat(arrayC1.concat(arrayF1.concat(arrayMo1.concat(arrayTe1.concat(arrayHe1.concat(arrayMon1.concat(arrayAda1)))))))))))))))),

         nomeGabinete= $("#nomedoGabinetes").text(), nomeProcessador= $("#nomedoProcessador").text(), nomePlacamae =$("#nomedoPlacamae").text(), nomeMemoria = $("#nomedoMemoria").text(), nomedoPlacadevideo =$("#nomedoPlacadevideo").text(), nomeHD = $("#nomedoHD").text(), nomeSSD= $("#nomedoSSD").text(), nomeSO=$("#nomedoSO").text(), nomeGravador=$("#nomedoGravador").text(), nomeWcooler=$("#nomedoWcooler").text(), nomeCooler=$("#nomedoCooler").text(), nomefonte=$("#nomedoFonte").text(), nomeMouse=$("#nomedoMouse").text(), nomeTeclado=$("#nomedoTeclado").text(), nomeHeadset=$("#nomedoHeadset").text(),   nomeMonitor=$("#nomedoMonitor").text(), nomeAdaptador=$("#nomedoAdaptador").text(), valortotal=$("#valortotalprodutos").val(), nome=$("#nome").val(), email=$("#email").val();

 $.ajax('enviar_montepc.php',{
          type: 'POST',
          data:{'arrayValor':arrayValor, 'arrayQtd':arrayQtd, 'nome':nome, 'email':email, 'nomeGabinete':nomeGabinete, 'nomeProcessador':nomeProcessador, 'nomePlacamae':nomePlacamae, 'nomeMemoria':nomeMemoria, 'nomedoPlacadevideo':nomedoPlacadevideo, 'nomeHD':nomeHD, 'nomeSSD':nomeSSD, 'nomeSO':nomeSO, 'nomeGravador':nomeGravador, 'nomeWcooler':nomeWcooler, 'nomeCooler':nomeCooler, 'nomefonte':nomefonte, 'nomeMouse':nomeMouse,  'nomeTeclado':nomeTeclado, 'nomeHeadset':nomeHeadset,'nomeMonitor':nomeMonitor, 'nomeAdaptador':nomeAdaptador, 'valortotal':valortotal }
        }).done(function(r){
          if(r==0){
              $.alert({

                content: 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso',
            });


          }   
          else if(r==1){

            $.alert({
            title: 'Atenção!',
                content: 'Ocorrou um erro ao ser enviado o e-mail',
            });

          } 

        }).fail(function(){
             $.alert({
                content: 'Tente novamente',
            });
        });



      });
```

A parte do PHP está funcionando normalmente.

Vlw pela ajuda.

Comment: Perdão pelo comentário não relacionado à pergunta, mas já pensou em usar um framework como o [Vue](http://vuejs.org/)? Ajuda bastante a diminuir essas linhas monstras.

Comment: Mostra algum erro ou simplesmente não retorna nada? Já tentou enviar os dados direto para o PHP sem AJAX?

Comment: Nao sei se é o caso,  mas em `sql` por exemplo concatenação com nulo  anula todo o resultado. Já testou virificse nulidade antes de concatenar? Ou entregar arrays vazios em vez de nulos?

Comment: Não estou usando sql pra isso! Eu estou passando tudo para o php, guardando em uma variável e mandando pro e-mail.
Ele manda pro e-mail sem erro nenhum, só que se eu não seleciono o que não é obrigatório e seleciono algo posterior, ele não manda o valor, nem a quantidade, apenas manda o nome

Comment: Sistema Operacional: 8.1 Valor Unitário R$ 765,00 Quantidade: 1 Gravador: dvd sata Valor Unitário R$ 423.424,00 Quantidade: 1 Water Cooler: nao escolhido Cooler: nao escolhido 
Fonte: asdadas Valor Unitário R$ 0,00 Quantidade: 
Mouse: nao escolhido 
Teclado: razer Valor Unitário R$ 0,00 Quantidade: 
Monitor: nao escolhido Adaptador: nao escolhidoValor
 total da compra é: R$ 562.663,18

Chega assim no e-mail, tipo eu não escolhi o Water Cooler, aí a fonte e o teclado ele não retorna valor unitário nem a quantidade

Comment: Poderia postar na pergunta o HTML e o JS para ver como estão sendo selecionados essas opções? Coloque tb o código de como é manipulado essas arrays. O problema pode estar nisso.

Comment: Opa, coloquei na pergunta lá! Se puder dar uma luz, agradeço.